# Wit AI partial translation causing a problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nlp, wit-ai

I am using old code from a unity project but the wit.ai bot I've created is new. They have changed the way the response is sent and they use partial translations as well which does not work in my app. How do I remove the partial translations and only use the last chunk? I am using C# since the project is in Unity.

In the code snippet attached, the wit.ai checks for every word now. I just want the final result of the entire text. How do I do that?

```
{
  "text": "Open"
}
{
  "text": "Open driver"
}
{
  "text": "Open driver's"
}
{
  "text": "Open driver's door"
}
{
  "text": "Open driver's door."
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "speech": {
    "confidence": 0.9983,
    "tokens": [
      {
        "end": 1260,
        "start": 260,
        "token": "Open"
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Open",
  "traits": {}
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "speech": {
    "confidence": 0.8021,
    "tokens": [
      {
        "end": 1260,
        "start": 260,
        "token": "Open"
      },
      {
        "end": 1800,
        "start": 1260,
        "token": "driver's"
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Open driver's",
  "traits": {}
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "speech": {
    "confidence": 0.8374,
    "tokens": [
      {
        "end": 1260,
        "start": 260,
        "token": "Open"
      },
      {
        "end": 1800,
        "start": 1260,
        "token": "driver's"
      },
      {
        "end": 2040,
        "start": 1800,
        "token": "door."
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Open driver's door.",
  "traits": {}
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "is_final": true,
  "speech": {
    "confidence": 0.8374,
    "tokens": [
      {
        "end": 1260,
        "start": 260,
        "token": "Open"
      },
      {
        "end": 1800,
        "start": 1260,
        "token": "driver's"
      },
      {
        "end": 2040,
        "start": 1800,
        "token": "door."
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Open driver's door.",
  "traits": {}
}
```

I would only like to get the below as response:

```
"text": "Open driver's door.",
  "traits": {}
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "is_final": true,
  "speech": {
    "confidence": 0.8374,
    "tokens": [
      {
        "end": 1260,
        "start": 260,
        "token": "Open"
      },
      {
        "end": 1800,
        "start": 1260,
        "token": "driver's"
      },
      {
        "end": 2040,
        "start": 1800,
        "token": "door."
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Open driver's door.",
  "traits": {}
}
```